# Regex whitespace followed by special character

Tags: regex

Hey guys I thought I had this locked down, but testing proved otherwise.

I need a regex that simply matches a whitespace followed by an @ symbol

ie. ' @'

Currently my regex of

```
str.match(/[\s\@](.+)$/)
```

Returns true is there is a whitespace AND an @ anywhere in the string

Example of what **not** to match 'asd asd@'

Example of what **should** match 'asd @asd'

I'm stuck, help appreciated :/

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use

```
str.match(/\s@/)
```

Comment: I'm such a spas, so simple.

Over complicating it because originally I was looking for non greedy matches of '@', but couldn't figure out why I can't do the same with /\s\@(.+)$/

Comment: Sorry One more thing I should have mentioned, the original regex was returning from the match something like.

["asd @asd", " @asd", index: 5, input: "asd @asd"] 

the new one 

[" @", index: 5, input: "asd @asd"] 

How do i get the second property of the match back

Comment: If you use `str.match(/\s@(.+)/)`, then `.+` will match everything after the `@` and capture it just like in your first regex. Since that part of the regex is not necessary to determine a match or a non-match, I had removed it. Just put it back in if you need it.